# API how to hide response when you put in production (Angular V16)

Tags: angular

Here is an example of one call to API:

```
public getQuery(query: string) {
   const commonUrl: string = `https://api.tvmaze.com/${query}`;
   return this.http.get(commonUrl)   
}
        
public getShowsList() {
   const url: string = `shows`;
   return this.getQuery(url).pipe(
        tap((response) => console.debug(response)),
        catchError((error) => {
              console.debug(error);
              return of({});
        })
    )   
}
```

I wouldn't see the response on my console (only in production) with Angular V16
PS: I'm a newbie in Angular, so please give me some details

Comment: Looks like you have not been subscribed. You can add `.subscribe()` after the pipe closing bracket.

Comment: You haven't understand my question
I speak of response in "success" and/or "error" of the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some projects I used custom logging service for that purpose. But we hid all logs outside of debug version:

**custom-logging.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomLoggingService {

  constructor() { }

  log(message?: any) {
    if (environment.isDebug) {
      console.log(message);
    }
  }
}
```

then in your environment file we had something similar to this:

**environment.ts** - for debug and other

```
export const environment = {
  ...defaults,
  isDebug: true,
  remouteApi: 'url for debug'
}
```

**environment.prod.ts** - for prod

```
export const environment = {
  ...defaults,
  isDebug: false,
  remouteApi: 'url for prod'
}
```

example of usage:

```
...your component
constructor(
  private myLogger: CustomLoggingService) {
  this.myLogger.log('visible only in debug');
}
```